# Calculate cell value using selected option in table

Tags: javascript, checkbox, html-table, selection

I'm trying to build a single table that houses all of the pricing options I need. This should be simple, but I'm getting NaN responses in the cell meant to contain the calculation.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
  <table border="2">
   <tr>
    <th>Subscription Memberships</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Subscription Type:
    <select id="duration">
     <option value="1MonthSub">Monthly Subscription</option>
     <option value="3MonthSub">Quarterly Subscription</option>
     <option value="6MonthSub">Bi-Annual Subscription</option>
     <option value="yearSub">Yearly Subscription</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="discount">
    I am eligible for the student, military, or senior discount.</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><span id="calculated"></span></td>
   </tr>
  </table>

  <script>
   function calcPrice() {

    //Variables
    var choice = document.getElementById("duration");
    var dur = choice.options[choice.selectedIndex].text;
    var price;
    var per;
    var output;

    switch(dur) {
    case "1MonthSub":
     price = 65;
     per = " / month";
     break;
    case "3MonthSub":
     price = 220;
     per = " / 3 months";
     break;
    case "6MonthSub":
     price = 440;
     per = " / 6 months";
     break;
    case "yearSub":
     price = 900;
     per = " / year";
     break;
    }//end switch

    if (document.getElementById("discount").checked) {
     price = price * 0.9;
    }//end if

    output = price + per;
    return output;
   }//end calcPrice()

   document.getElementById("calculated").innerHTML = calcPrice();
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

The NaN cell SHOULD calculate the price based on the option selected from the dropdown and the true/false value of the checkbox. I've tried moving the script portions around, and when they're placed before the table nothing shows up in the cell at all. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed:

`var dur = choice.options[choice.selectedIndex].text;`

To:

`var dur = choice.options[choice.selectedIndex].value;`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
  <table border="2">
   <tr>
    <th>Subscription Memberships</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Subscription Type:
    <select id="duration">
     <option value="1MonthSub">Monthly Subscription</option>
     <option value="3MonthSub">Quarterly Subscription</option>
     <option value="6MonthSub">Bi-Annual Subscription</option>
     <option value="yearSub">Yearly Subscription</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="discount">
    I am eligible for the student, military, or senior discount.</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><span id="calculated"></span></td>
   </tr>
  </table>

  <script>
   function calcPrice() {

    //Variables
    var choice = document.getElementById("duration");
    var dur = choice.options[choice.selectedIndex].value;
    var price;
    var per;
    var output;

    switch(dur) {
    case "1MonthSub":
     price = 65;
     per = " / month";
     break;
    case "3MonthSub":
     price = 220;
     per = " / 3 months";
     break;
    case "6MonthSub":
     price = 440;
     per = " / 6 months";
     break;
    case "yearSub":
     price = 900;
     per = " / year";
     break;
    }//end switch

    if (document.getElementById("discount").checked) {
     price = price * 0.9;
    }//end if

    output = price + per;
    return output;
   }//end calcPrice()

   document.getElementById("calculated").innerHTML = calcPrice();
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```